# Kissing another person of same gender but with no sexual attraction

Tags: kissing

Is it wrong for two women to kiss each other on the lips... There is no sexual attraction among them they are just as sisters..  They are straight and very sure about this..  Is it wrong for them to do so?

Comment: Is it a local custom or more of a phase that "those" two women are currently going through in life?

Answer (score 1):

Likely it's not allowed.

Kissing lips is more common with the older generations and also more common for warmer cultures (Arab or Latin cultures)

I've seen parents, grandparents do this ie it's usually when a junior member of the family makes a senior member very proud.

It's very odd for two adults to do this. It's generally recommended to show your affection for other believers by hugging and kissing them. But there are certain limits

**I selected these two narrations from: Usul Kafi, volume 2, Chapter of kissing (تقبیل):‌**

Narration1:

> *مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ یَحْیَى عَنِ الْعَمْرَكِیِّ بْنِ عَلِیٍّ عَنْ عَلِیِّ بْنِ جَعْفَرٍ عَنْ أَبِی الْحَسَنِ ع قَالَ مَنْ قَبَّلَ لِلرَّحِمِ ذَا
> قَرَابَةٍ فَلَیْسَ عَلَیْهِ شَیْ ءٌ وَ قُبْلَةُ الْأَخِ عَلَى الْخَدِّ
> وَ قُبْلَةُ الْإِمَامِ بَیْنَ عَیْنَیْهِ*
>
> There is nothing against one whom kisses his kin or his brother (in
> faith) at his cheeks or his forehead

Narration2:

> *وَ عَنْهُ عَنْ أَحْمَدَ بْنِ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ خَالِدٍ عَنْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ سِنَانٍ عَنْ أَبِى الصَّبَّاحِ مَوْلَى آلِ سَامٍ عَنْ أَبِى عَبْدِ اللَّهِ ع قَالَ لَیْسَ الْقُبْلَةُ عَلَى الْفَمِ إِلَّا لِلزَّوْجَةِ أَوِ الْوَلَدِ الصَّغِیرِ*
>
> Kissing the lips is for no
>
> one other than your spouse or (your) little children

Answer (score 0):

In more than one arabic countries when we want to greet each other we kiss each other cheeks or we put cheek on cheek and kiss on air. For same genders friend or relative sure without sex desires.